# Symfony test get form errors

Tags: phpunit, symfony

If I have a functional test like:

```
public function testCreate()
{

    $client = $this->makeClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('POST', "/post/new");

    $form = $crawler->selectButton("Create Post")->form();
    $values = $form->getPhpValues();

    $values['post']['title'] = 'test';
    $values['post']['content'] = null; // Should fail because it isn't a string.


    $crawler = $client->request($form->getMethod(), $form->getUri(), $values,
        $form->getPhpFiles());
    assertEquals() // What goes here?
}
```

How do I use the `crawler` to get the form errors and compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions for you:

1. Use the crawler to check for the actually rendered form errors in your rendered HTML code.
2. Make use of the profiler and access the form data collector: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll go with 1, I assume I'll have to use `filter` and there's not a shortcut?

Comment: Yes, just use `filter()` like you do it otherwise.